# Cypress: function of click random element and storage its title to verify later

Tags: javascript, cypress

this is my first question of stackoverflow community, I am currently working with Cypress and have created test case that   randomly clicks an element from a list. I am trying to also get the text from that same function for my case, i am trying to do;

- Open main site
- Select any elements from elements section (randomly)
- Once details page for the selected elements is opened verify its title equals to the titles selected in previous page
- The problem is I am unable to return the title properly I can't get
  the titles to be equal. The code I currently have is:

```js
    context('Select feature of site', () => {
       it('Randomly select element of elements section', () => {
           cy.visit('website url')
           cy.wait(600)
           cy.get('.element_container')
            .children()
            .eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * 44))
            .click({force: true}) 
            .each(($containerSubNewsListWrapper) => {
           cy.get($containerSubNewsListWrapper).click()
            // cy.title().should('eq','') i stucked here
           })
       }) })
```

I click randomly but I'm stuck on syncing the title,i would need to retrieve a title for an item selected randomly and store it somewhere, verify afterwards.
I appreciate any ideas

Comment: Can you explain a bit why have you used `each()` after clicking the randomly chosen element ?

Comment: Hello, first of all my question has been resolved thanks to you. thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question. I'm new to this field and I couldn't randomly click on the child element without using each . Have I made an unnecessary use?

Comment: If using `each` solves your use case than that is OK. Its a legit cypress command, so you are good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save the title in a variable using an alias you can do something like this:

```js
cy.title().as('title1')
```

Then, When you are inside a different page and want to validate that the title matches the previous title you can do something like:

```js
cy.get("@title1").then((title1) => {
  cy.title().then((title2) => {.   //get the title of the current page
    expect(title1).to.equal(title2)
  })
})
```